# how to check where exist the requested word in txt file using PHP

Tags: php, html-table, preg-match, text-files, readfile

i have a php code that read text files and allow the user to make a search then it display the result in an html  table that contains **filename** and **line number** each file can handle multiple lines.

all txt files composed of 10 categories where each category contains some text in it.

[image]

> category 1
>
> 0.74 ±
>
> 0.18 ° C in the 100 years ended 2005. According to the IPCC, "most of the >observed increase in global temperature since the middle of the 20th century is >largely due to increased greenhouse gases (greenhouse gases) By humans.
>
> Most of the sun's rays penetrate the atmosphere to reach the earth's surface. >Most of these rays are located at the visible wavelength (the sun's light that >the eye sees). Therefore, the Earth's surface is heated during the day. The >earth can not fully absorb solar energy. If this happens, the Earth's >temperature will reach the melting point , And the end of life on them
>
> category 2
>
> The earth is heated to absorb the heat of the sun, then the surface of the >earth returns the absorbed energy energy back into the atmosphere, and in the >absence of any complex effects, thermal equilibrium occurs. In this case, the >earth's surface temperature is about -2.3 ° C, and the energy that the Earth is >transmitting is infrared (this is contrary to reality).
>
> In fact, complexities, where the atmosphere holds part of the infrared; because >of the particles of carbon dioxide and water vapor that absorbs most of the >infrared radiation, and the part that is not absorbed out of the atmosphere >into space, and the absorbing part of the infrared The atmosphere has a >temperature rise

the expected result:

[image]

i know that i must includes these categories in an **array**  and while the system read read the files it make a compare with the array's element  once it found a match it display the category name in second row under the line number.

i do not know how to write this idea in php can anyone help me ?

## code:

```
<?php

$result = [];
if(isset($_POST["search"]))
{
    $search =$_POST['name'];
    echo "the word  $search exist: <br><br>";
    foreach(glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/readfiletest/*.txt") as $txts)
    {

        $line = 1;
        $temp   = [];
        $myFileLink = fopen($txts, 'r');
        while(!feof($myFileLink))
        {
            $myFileContents = fgets($myFileLink);
            if( preg_match_all('/('.preg_quote($search,'/').')/i', $myFileContents, $matches))
            {

                $temp['filename'] = basename ($txts);
                foreach($matches[1] as $match)
                {
                    $temp['lines'][] = $line;
                }
            }
            ++$line;
        }
        fclose($myFileLink);

        $result[] = $temp;
    }

    //display the table
    echo '<table class = "minimalistBlack" border=2>';

 $filenameHtml    = '<tr>';
 $lineNumberHtml    = '<tr>';
 foreach ($result as $item)
 {
    $filename = isset($item['filename']) ? $item['filename'] : '';
    $lines = isset($item['lines']) ? implode(',',$item['lines']) : '';
//$filenameHtml .= "<th>$filename</th>";
    $new_filename = str_replace('.txt', '.pdf',$filename);
    $filenameHtml .= !empty($filename) ? "<th><a href ='".$new_filename."'target='_blank'>$filename</a></th>" : ''; // added !empty()
    $lineNumberHtml .= !empty($lines) ? "<td>$lines</td>" : ''; // added !empty()
  }
    $filenameHtml    .= '</tr>';
    $lineNumberHtml  .= '</tr>';

    echo $filenameHtml.$lineNumberHtml;
    echo '</table>';
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar-sa">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style>
          #form {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
        background: linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
        margin: auto;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;


        font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #09C;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border: inset 1px solid #333;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

    </style
    <body>
    <div id = "form">
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
          <h1 align =center > Search Form </h1>
          <p>enter your string <input type ="text"  id = "idName"  name="name" /></p>
          <p align =center ><input type ="Submit" name ="search" value= "Search" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is "category1" and so on only a placeholder for a random word, or are they really named so? Also, are they different from file to file, or always the same?

Comment: @Twinfriends they are always the same categories but the size of each paragraph under these categories will be different from file to file === and no the names are (local, national , international .....)

Comment: @Twinfriends SO DO YOU KNOW HOW TO solve this because it took me a lot of time in order to find it and still no success